# Is it a best practice to have a method in AngularJS's directive isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know, when we have directives with isolated scope, is it a good practice to have a method in isolated scope or we should create a method in directive's parent scope & pass it as a reference to the directive with "&".

For example in the following code, I have created "doSomething" method in directive's isolated scope & that directive is used three times(as per data). So, now does angular creates the method "doSomething" object 3 times in each isolated scope or will it be only one method shared by 3 isolated scopes?

```js
angular.module("app", []).directive('appDirective', appDirective);

function appDirective() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<span>{{obj.name}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.flag" ng-change="doSmothing(obj.flag)"></span> {{obj}}',
    replace: false,
    controller: controllerFunction,
    scope: {
      obj: '=appDirective'
    }
  };

  function controllerFunction($scope) {
    $scope.doSmothing = function(flag) {
      console.log($scope.obj, flag);
    }

  }
  return directive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">

<body>
  <div>
    <ul ng-init="data=[{name:'Shiva',flag:false},{name:'Kumar',flag:false},{name:'Govind',flag:false}]">
      <li ng-repeat="d in data">
        <p app-directive="d"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes if it is reusable component then go for isolated scope

Comment: Yes, its a reusable component. I worry about if I use that directive 100 times, will the method "doSomething" created in 100 isolated scopes, No?

Comment: if your are using 100 times on single page at a time, then it would make impact on performance, still depends directive contains any event, watcher, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
No, directive do not have any watcher. Just onclick event & event handler function. Right now, there is no much performance issue, but I would like to know the best practice for this kind

Comment: I think in your case you must go with isolated scope..& it is best practice if you have part of code which is repeating on same page

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Parkar

Answer (score 0):

in the angular docs, I found the exact explinations for my doubt. It is ok to put the "doSomething" method in side scope which is in "controller", because, The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives. This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior.

[check angular doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)